# default value for select mat-option in angular along with formControlName

Tags: angular

I am using formControlName for a field in form that is selectable:-

```
<form [formGroup]="sPFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="addSP(sPFormGroup)">

        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select formControlName="tag" placeholder="Tag">
                <mat-option value="SP">SP</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="REVERSE_SP">REVERSE_SP</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Now how can I set the default value for this select field?. I tried using [(value)] = "selected" and defining selected as SP in .ts file but that is not working. I think formControlName and [(value)] does not work together. Please check?

Comment: You can set value of tag filed in form i.e `this.sPFormGroup.get('tag').setValue('SP')` this should work

Comment: but this will be changed right as the selection changes?

Comment: That will set the default selected value but on selection of any value from dropdown you could call a method and inside that method set the value same like above line I pasted you can use that inside that method and set the passed value

Comment: Thanks. Also, should I use this.sPFormGroup.get('tag').setValue(this.defaultTag, {onlySelf: true}); Is the parameter {onlySelf: true} required?

Comment: Not in your case I believe.

Comment: During form submission, I am validating the entire form. can you tell me the exact use of this parameter. Not able to understand.